# Instantiating Window from AppDelegate Failing in Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, xcode, instantiation, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I'm using Xcode 11 and Swift 5.0.  I copied over my code from another app that used Swift 4.2.  That code instantiates a tabBarViewController in the AppDelegate, changes the window to the tabBarVC and shows it if certain conditions are met.  But it is not working in Swift 5.0 and Xcode 11.  Here's the code:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Run Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Check Firebase Auth to see if the user is signed in already.
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        print ("User is already authenticated and signed in.")
        // Check to make sure the user is stored in local settings.
        if let appUser = LocalStorageService.loadCurrentUser() {
            print ("Local storage has a user: \(appUser)")
            // Create a tab bar controller.
            let tabBarVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.tabBarController)
            // Show it
            window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        return true // If auth has a user and there is local user, window changes.
    } else {
        print ("No Authenticated current user, must proceed with Login.")
        return false
    }
}
```

The tabBarVC is populated successfully, but window remains nil.  Then the app shows a different view controller.  Nothing is different in the code from the original app that I can see.  And that one still works.  Thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `SceneDelegate` from the Navigator and the following sections from the `info.plist` dealing with Scenes and now it works as expected (the other app did not have the `SceneDelegate` or these sections in the `info.plist`.  I assume they were added when the project was created in Xcode 11):

[image]

I read about scenes for iOS 13 in the Apple Documentation.  I don't plan to use scenes, but if someone does want to use scenes, they will have to determine how to configure the `info.plist` to allow the instantiation of a VC in the AppDelegate.

Comment: See the duplicate marked by Matt if you want to use scenes.  That answer puts the window in the scene delegate.  This answer removes the scene delegate entirely.  Scenes are not required.